BUD AND BARBEQUE
What is the meaning of "bud" in "BUD AND BARBEQUE"?
According to The Free Dictionary, "bud" can mean, for examples:

To put forth or produce buds
To develop or grow from or as if from a bud
To be in an undeveloped stage or condition.
To reproduce asexually by forming a bud.

However, it seems "bud" in "BUD AND BARBEQUE" doesn't have the above meanings.

"Bud" can also be short for "buddy", usually meaning "a male friend", who is exactly the sort of person you might go to a barbeque event with.

BTW, the correct spelling is barbecue. I think people started writing it with a 'q' because of the abbreviations 'Bar-B-Q' or 'BBQ'.

Thank you, Kate :).

"Bud" is slang for Budweiser brand beer. This is clarified in the description of the event:

...a voucher for a mouthwatering beef on a bun paired perfectly with a cold Budweiser.


For what it's worth, Budweiser would really like that slang to be normalized but at least in my area, it does not seem to be in casual usage. They persistently use it in much of their advertising, though, or in sponsored events like this one.

That Bud definitely not to be confused with one of the best beers in the world, Czech Budweiser Budvar.

Thank you for your response!

"Bud" is also one of the many slang terms for marijuana. Being invited to a friend's house for "Bud and barbecue" could be an invitation to drink beer and eat, or smoke marijuana and eat. (But for the event you linked, it's definitely beer.)

Thank you for pointing it out!
